# Showing individual points in SChartLineSeries

Tags: ios, shinobi

Using ShinobiChart's `SChartLineSeries` chart type, I'm trying to enable the display of individual points with a circle (as in [this](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiCharts/2.3.0/Standard/Normal/docs/markdown_files/ChartsUserGuide.html#The%20Anatomy%20of%20the%20chart) example from ShinobiControls' user guide). Currently, the line plots without any individual points marked.

The user guide says this can indeed be done (as an option to be enabled) but without specifying how. And after scouring the documentation, I can't find this option anywhere. Anyone know if this is actually possible? Note: the `SChartScatterSeries` *does* offer this option, but I'm using the `SChartLineSeries` to take advantage of the built-in time series support, so need to stick with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable point visibility. An `SChartLineSeries` has a style property - which is of type `SChartLineSeriesStyle`. This is a subclass of `SChartScatterSeriesStyle`, so you have access to a pointStyle property. You just need to set your `pointStyle` to show points:

```
- (SChartSeries *)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart seriesAtIndex:(int)index
{
    SChartLineSeries *series = [SChartLineSeries new];
    series.style.pointStyle.showPoints = YES;
    return series;
}
```

You can then control the appearance of the points using the properties available on this style. For more information check out the following classes in the API documentation:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiCharts/2.3.0/Premium/Normal/Classes/SChartPointStyle.html

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiCharts/2.3.0/Premium/Normal/Classes/SChartBasePointStyle.html

Hope that helps :)